# Clicking button element that has event listener attached refreshes page

Tags: javascript, function

I have a problem with my function, in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wotsepotse/g1Ljjgc7/1/)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", init, false);

function init() {
  let naam = document.getElementById("naam").addEventListener("blur", checkNaam, false);
  let startKnop = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", startClicked, false);
}

function checkNaam(event) {
  const regEX = /^\d[A-Z]{2}\d{1,}K$/;
  let naam = document.getElementById("naam");
  let knop = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

  if (regEX.test(naam.value)) {
    knop.removeAttribute("disabled");
    knop.setAttribute("enable");
  }
}

function startClicked(event) {
  let knop2 = document.getElementById("keuze1");
  knop2.removeAttribute("disabled");

  let knop3 = document.getElementById("keuze2");
  knop3.removeAttribute("disabled");

  toonVraag();
}

function toonVraag(event) {
  let vraag = document.getElementById('vraag');
  vraag.innerHTML = "Hallo";

}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: large;
}

form div {
  margin: 2em;
}

#verslag {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Examen p5</title>
  <script src="scripts/examen.js.pdf.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/afblijven.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <h1>Enquêtetool</h1>
      <p>Geef eerst een correcte code in: start met een cijfer, dan 2 hoofdletters, vervolgens 1 of meerdere cijfers en de code eindigt met een K. Druk dan op start om de enquête te starten...</p>
      <label for="naam">Code: </label><input type="text" id="naam" />
    </div>
    <button disabled>Start</button>
    <div>
      <p id="vraag">Een vraag</p>
      <button id="keuze1" disabled>Keuze1</button>
      <button id="keuze2" disabled>Keuze2</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <section id="verslag">
    <h1>Overzicht antwoorden</h1>
    <table>

    </table>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

The code you have to put in is

> 1KK1K

My problem is that once the listener handler is called:

```
function startClicked(event) {
    let knop2 = document.getElementById("keuze1");
    knop2.removeAttribute("disabled");

    let knop3 = document.getElementById("keuze2");
    knop3.removeAttribute("disabled");

    toonVraag();
}
```

it automatically refreshes the page (back to the default).

Note: I can't change the HTML directly, it needs to go through JavaScript.

Comment: `<button>` elements on a form submit the form by default. Add an `event.preventDefault()` in your `startClicked()` handler

Comment: Or change it to `<button type="button">` so it doesn't default to `type="submit"`

Comment: @mhodges or set `type=button`, would that work too? of course, he can't change the html so that's neither here nor there I guess.

Comment: @dgig Right, yeah if the OP could change the HTML that would definitely be a valid solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button element acts as if it was a form, so its refreshing.

You can either fix it in the JavaScript or HTML:

JavaScript:

- add `event.preventDefault()` to the beginning of your button handler to stop the button from doing it's 'default action', or

HTML:

- add `type="button"` to the button in the HTML because [it defaults as a 'submit'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

https://jsfiddle.net/g1Ljjgc7/2/ is an updated version of your fiddle.

Comment: `return false` is non-standard, `event.preventDefault()` is the conforming way to do that.

Comment: @Barmar fair enough; I'll change it, I didn't actually know that! thanks

Comment: Not to mention, `type="button"` requires modifying the HTML, which is an explicit requirement that you cannot.

Comment: @mhodges noted, but I think it might be useful for others? I could remove it?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yeah, I thought about that right after I typed it. I removed that part of my comment. I would probably make a mention about the distinction though